Certificate chain length: 0

C:\Users\PC\Documents\Github_repo\flutter_aplication_1> keytool  -list -keystore 
 C:\Users\PC\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey Enter keystore password


*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************


androiddebugkey, Sep 12, 2023, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate chain length: 0


I want to get a certificate from the keystore for me, I use my mobile app configuration but what I get is that the certificate chain length is 0

You mean you want to get a certificate fingerprint?

I was looking for a SHA1 certificate fingerprint for my key, and the fingerprint wasn't displaying when I run the keytool -list -v command on my debug keystore, and Certificate chain length was 0. The keystore didn't have any password (i.e. and empty string "") just like in your case, and only after setting the password with keytool -storepasswd the fingerprints would be displayed and the Certificate chain length would be set to 1.
